# How to get good quality album photos from FB api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve good quality album photos from graph API. but when i send get request of albums data, they provide me only 130*130 resolution photos. so! how can i get full size photos from graph API?

my graph API URL : `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=albums{photos{picture,id}}&access_token=my_token`

`"picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/q82/s130x130"`

Comment: The `images` structure below `photos` holds all available image sizes, you can pick one from there.

Comment: `me/albums?fields=photos{images}`

Comment: okay. got it. thank you.

Comment: But, it provides some duplicate photos in json data. I'm unable to analyse that data. i want to do a slideshow of each album with their photos.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by duplicates. Inside `images` you’ll find different size versions of the _same_ photo, you need to pick one of those you like.

Comment: okay. i've done it. `me/albums?fields=albums{photos{picture,images}}` helps me for showing different resolution picture of same picture.